# How to send Mail from Android app

Tags: android, sendmail, android-spinner

I have developed a very simple Android app where user has to select items from the Spinners and type some texts in a Message box. Then the job is to SUBMIT. If the user tap on SUBMIT the whole selected data would send to a specific email address directly. After successful sending there comes a Dialog box showing some Thank You message. It should be mentioned here that I've used 4 Spinners and 1 Edittext box.

Now I'm looking for the code to SUBMIT button's action. Please help me out.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never written an email sending function in Android. However, the alternative way instead of sending the email through your app is to fire the intent to other email app.

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

String receiver = "someone@somewhere.com";
String subject  = "your email subject";
String body     = "your email body";

emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, receiver);
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);

startActivity(emailIntent);
```

Also, don't forget adding permission in your AndroidManifest.

Answer (score 0):

```
I used it in my app. here is the code.

When multiple Application to send email handling it to others applications

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send your email in:"));  

Supplying Message Content

Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);  

String aEmailList[] = { "user@gmail.com","user2@gmail.com" };  
String aEmailCCList[] = { "user3@gmail.com","user4@gmail.com"};  
String aEmailBCCList[] = { "user5@gmail.com" };  

emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, aEmailList);  
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_CC, aEmailCCList);  
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_BCC, aEmailBCCList);  

emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "My subject");  

emailIntent.setType("plain/text");  
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "My message body.");  

startActivity(emailIntent);
```